# How to change Temp URL - RHEL & Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

`RHEL, MySQL` `Drupal7`, `Apache`
Drupal 7 showing links with `/?q=node/`, i have tried to Clean URLs, which has failed. I am changing in `.htaccess` `drupal7` file but its not showing any effect. I have URL `1.1.1.1/drupal/?q=node/1` which i have to replace by `1.1.1.1/drupal/aboutus`

Already enable

> `RewriteBase /drupal`
>
> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]`
>
> `RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

NOTE -*The clean URL test failed* - Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Those rewrite rules you've got enabled are for redirecting non-www to www. Make sure you've got this rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: URL Rewrite is not happening.  
I have URL `1.1.1.1/drupal/?q=node/1` which i have to replace by `1.1.1.1/drupal/aboutus`

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: Yes, i have done lots of workaround but could not succeed, seems its a Drupal 7 bug on RHEL. Can